# How to setup simple AJAX properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So if I set this up without ajax, it works fine. As soon as I include ajax, the page loads the url bar with "?search=63105" but nothing displays in the results div

HTML + Jquery

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search"/>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
 $("form").on('submit', (function(e){
   var search = $('#search').val();
   var dataString = 'search=' + search;
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "searchpost.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
        }
     });
   });
 });
</script>
```

PHP Page

```
<?php
require_once('../config/db.php');
require_once('../customLIB/pdo_db.php');
require_once('../models/test.php');
$SalesRep = new SalesRep();

if ($_POST['search']) {
 $data = $_POST['search'];
 $rep = $SalesRep->getRep($data);

 if (!empty($rep)) {
    echo $rep->name;
  } else {
    echo "No sales reps found..";
  }
}
?>
```

Again, even when the results should be shown, nothing is showing. The PHP works, this is no problem with that.

Thanks.

Comment: *without ajax, it works fine* are you sure? Because the `<form>` without a method is going to GET not POST

Comment: Lawrence Cherone Yes because without ajax, I include the method and action. If I include that now, it goes to the searchpost.php page instead of an AJAX call without page reload.

Comment: yeah thats what preventDefault is for

Comment: `jquery-1.9.1.js` — **Danger**. jQuery 1.x is no longer supported and has known security issues. Upgrade to a current version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form submit function, you have the line `e.preventDefault()`, however, the function never accepted the event argument `e`.

```
$("form").on('submit', (function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    //...
});
```

Should instead be

```
$("form").on('submit', (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //...
});
```

Since form submit is never prevented, the form submits as usual and the AJAX call doesn't get fully executed.

EDIT: Additionally, the following lines

```
var search = $('#search').val();
var dataString = 'search=' + search;
```

Should be within the submit function. Only then would it get the value of `#search` during the submission of the search.

EDIT4: Found out that doing `var dataString = 'search=' + search;` works anyway so EDIT2 can be disregarded.

EDIT2: Not too familiar with the PHP side of things, but POST-ing data usually is done with JavaScript objects. Try having `dataString` be

```
var dataString = { search: search };
```

Or better yet, have the form serialize itself

```
var dataString = $('form').serialize();
```

EDIT3: Found an extra parenthesis that might be the cause of the issue.

```
$("form").on('submit', -->(function(e){
```

Final code should be

```
$(function () {
    $("form").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "searchpost.php",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Same thing, does not work. It shows exactly the same.

Comment: How about replacing the `e.preventDefault` with a `return false` at the end of the submit function? Also, the lines that gets the value from $('#search') should be within the submit function.

Comment: Nope, same thing. This is so weird.

Comment: I don't have a submit button btw, just on enter press.

Comment: Lines are in the submit function now, same issue. Nothing has changed.

Comment: How about changing the `dataString` to be a JSON object instead. I don't have experience in PHP but assume it would work the same as other frameworks. Have something like `dataString = { search: search };`

Comment: Nope still nothing is happing. I can put an alert in the success function and it never alert me on submit. So still a problem in the ajax somewhere.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, is there any request sent in the Network tab?

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq Found an extra parenthesis that may be causing the issues.

Comment: "Not too familiar with the PHP side of things, but POST-ing data usually is done with JSON objects." — That's a JavaScript object, not a JSON object.

Comment: @Quentin rectified and TIL passing query strings into jQuery AJAX data works.

Comment: extra parenthesis was the issue. My gosh.

Answer (score -1):

You are using post method , change the post parameter
data: {'search':search}
And Insted of echo in PHP file, return the value from PHP.

Comment: Passing an object to `data` will result in jQuery converting it to the same string as is currently being constructed manually (although it will properly escape the input, but that isn't the issue here).

Comment: `echo` is out you output from PHP to the HTTP response body. `return` returns it to the calling expression *in PHP*  … and the code isn't inside a function, so that will just cause it to output nothing.